# PATCH to a Firestore cloud Database + Refit, Update single field (c#, wpf)

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore, patch, refit

I am trying to update a single attribute of a Firebase document.
I am using Refit (c#, wpf)

```
        [Patch("/projects/super-project-name/databases/(default)/documents/users/{userId}?updateMask.fieldPaths=licence")]
        public Task UpdateUserLicence3(string userId, [Body] Fields licence);
```

I have a 400 bad request and I wonder if the Refit Query doesn't contain a mistake somewhere.

What I know :

- Publishing the same request without the [Body] Fields licence=> remove my "licence" field" from my document and doesn't crash.
- GET methods on single user works too.

Thanks by advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found out what was going wrong :

The actual 'licence' attribute wasn't correct (the body).

To fix it:

1. I switch the 'type' from "Fields" to a string
2. I put into my string, my following body :

```
{
  "fields": {
    "Licence": {
      "stringValue": "hello world!"
    }
  }
}
```

using a website link this : https://jsontostring.com/